# Can't redirect buyer when he approves the payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using sandbox environment and PayPal Server side Java SDK V2

I have created an order with OrdersCreateRequest() API then i get this classical response including required links

```
{
 "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "status": "CREATED",
 "links": [
 {    xxxxxxxxx    },
{
    "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=XXXXXXXXXX",
    "rel": "approve",
    "method": "GET"
}  ,
{    xxxxxxxxx    },
{    xxxxxxxxx    },
{    xxxxxxxxx    },
  ]
 }
```

**In my business use case** , I need to redirect the buyer after he goes to approval page , put his credentials and confirm , i want to get token as parameter from redirected link

So i tested this process , the order status become approved but the page doesn't redirect   and it just reloads. 
I have tried to add this parameter to body of OrdersCreateRequest

```
 "application_context": { 
    "return_url ": "http://xxx.xx.xxx.x:9000/invoice/10/view" 
}
```

but the page still reloads after approvement.

In this situation I can't know when the buyer has approved the order in my app .

Comment: What is your issue exactly? After approval, the buyer will be directed to the return_url, and that return_url page will load.

Comment: the issue is that the page doesn't redirect buyer after approvement and instead it reloads

Comment: The approval happens at PayPal, and the buyer is redirected to your page. Perhaps you are referring to what happens after payment capture, not "approvement".  Is the payment captured, or not? Your question does not include any code or information related to payment capture, which it must if that is the problem.

Comment: I just doing live tests with postman
 the problem is not approvement as i said the status successfully change to approved, the problem is when the buyer approve the order  with this link https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=XXXXXXXXXX" he is not redirected  to my app with the token passed in URL so i can't be aware of approvement

Comment: Have you tested with a standard HTTP or HTTPS port

Comment: same problem , even with standard port